# Индрик-зверь

Tags: этимология

Если я ничего не путаю, именно так на Руси называли единорогов. Но было бы интересно узнать, откуда вообще взялось такое название? Навевает мысли о чем-то индуистском.
Спасибо

Comment: Неспроста навевает. )))
Арии наши общие с представителями высших индийских каст предки, а Индра - одно из имён Перуна.
В интернете информации об индрик-звере почти нет... Ужасно жаль! Так хочется узнать больше.

Answer (score 1):

Я не сталкивался с таким названием единорога. Правильнее будет другое - индрика (ошибочно) называли единорогом. Это был другой зверь, чисто русского "пантеона". Какой, сказать трудно, возможно даже водоплавающий грызун (см цитату ниже). В Википедии есть исчерпывающая информация.

> В многочисленных вариантах «Духовного стиха о Голубиной книге» имя этого зверя является в разных формах: Индрок, Индра, Кондрык, Белояндрик, Вындрик, Единорог, Единрог и Единор. Варианты имени могут быть сведены к двум: Индрик и Единорог. Первое название объясняется искажением либо имени енудра, то есть выдры (др.-греч. ἐνύδριος, ἔνυδρις), либо еньдропа (др.-греч. ὓδρωψ), морского зверя, известного в славянских списках «Физиолога».
>
> Замена имени «Индрик» именем «Единорог» объясняется, с одной стороны, звуковым сходством обоих названий (Инрог и Индрик), с другой — одинаковым символическим значением обоих зверей. Смешение это замечается уже в «Физиологах».
>
> Зверь Индрия или Индрик упоминается также в «Азбуковниках» и описывается как зверёк, похожий на пса, живущий в реке Ниле и убивающий крокодила. Здесь индрика путают и отождествляют с ихневмоном.
>
> В разных списках стиха о Голубиной книге находятся различные черты в изображении Индрика, но во всех он называется «всем зверям отец». Он ходит по подземелью, пропущает реки и кладязи, или живет на Фавор-горе; когда он поворотится, все звери ему поклоняются. Или же он живет на Святой горе, ест и пьет из Синего моря, никому обиды не делает. Или он ходит рогом по подземелью, аки солнце по поднебесью.
>
> Индрик-зверь упоминается и в одной былине в обычной роли зверя Скимена (см.: Русские былины старой и новой записи. — Отд. II. — № 19).
>
> В литературе часто встречается утверждение, что на фольклорный образ индрика повлияли находки ископаемых останков мамонта.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA_%28%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F%29